# Run a directive after the DOM has finished rendering AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an object that I will get it from an API which would take a considerable time, I want my directive to wait till it gets data.

Comment: please add a code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read up on [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). Now say your data is stored in `$scope.data`. If you have something like this

```
<div ng-if="data"></div>
```

This **div** will only get injected in the DOM when `$scope.data` exists, which means you can make it wait for data before it gets injected in the DOM.

Comment: great use of ng-if. i would add a placeholder for his custom directive inside the div

Comment: Ok good but my data is coming from diffrent API calls I dont know when all of them arrive so that I can run my directive

Comment: Well you could set the ng-if dependent on a different variable say something like  ```<div ng-if="dataLoaded">```
This way you can que your API calls into a series of promises and set ```$scope.dataLoaded=true``` at the end of those
If you wanna know more about promises and how to que them you can read more about that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)